# How to import MLflow tracking server WSGI application via Flask or FastAPI?

Tags: python, mlflow

MLflow provides a very cool tracking server, however, this server does not provide authentication or RBAC which is required for my needs.

I would like to add my own authentication and RBAC functionality. I think one way to accomplish this is to import the MLflow WSGI application object and add some middleware layers to perform authentication / authorization before passing requests through to the tracking server, essentially proxying requests through my custom middleware stack.

How do I go about doing this? I can see from [these docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/wsgi/) that I can use FastAPI to import another WSGI application and add custom middleware, but I'm not sure of a few things

1. Where do I find the MLflow tracking server WSGI app (where can it be imported from)?
2. How do I pass through the relevant arguments to the MLflow tracking server? I.e. the tracking server expects params to configure the backend storage layer, host, and port. If I just import the application object, how do I pass those parameters to it?

edit - it looks like the Flask application can be found here https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/mlflow/server/__init__.py#L28

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was actually very simple, below is an example using FastAPI to import and mount the MLflow WSGI application.

```
import os
import subprocess
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.wsgi import WSGIMiddleware

from mlflow.server import app as mlflow_app

app = FastAPI()
app.mount("/", WSGIMiddleware(mlflow_app))

BACKEND_STORE_URI_ENV_VAR = "_MLFLOW_SERVER_FILE_STORE"
ARTIFACT_ROOT_ENV_VAR = "_MLFLOW_SERVER_ARTIFACT_ROOT"
ARTIFACTS_DESTINATION_ENV_VAR = "_MLFLOW_SERVER_ARTIFACT_DESTINATION"
PROMETHEUS_EXPORTER_ENV_VAR = "prometheus_multiproc_dir"
SERVE_ARTIFACTS_ENV_VAR = "_MLFLOW_SERVER_SERVE_ARTIFACTS"
ARTIFACTS_ONLY_ENV_VAR = "_MLFLOW_SERVER_ARTIFACTS_ONLY"

def parse_args():
    a = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    a.add_argument("--host", type=str, default="0.0.0.0")
    a.add_argument("--port", type=str, default="5000")
    a.add_argument("--backend-store-uri", type=str, default="sqlite:///mlflow.db")
    a.add_argument("--serve-artifacts", action="store_true", default=False)
    a.add_argument("--artifacts-destination", type=str)
    a.add_argument("--default-artifact-root", type=str)
    a.add_argument("--gunicorn-opts", type=str, default="")
    a.add_argument("--n-workers", type=str, default=1)
    return a.parse_args()

def run_command(cmd, env, cwd=None):
    cmd_env = os.environ.copy()
    if cmd_env:
        cmd_env.update(env)
    child = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd, env=cmd_env, cwd=cwd, text=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE
    )
    child.communicate()
    exit_code = child.wait()
    if exit_code != 0:
        raise Exception("Non-zero exitcode: %s" % (exit_code))
    return exit_code

def run_server(args):
    env_map = dict()
    if args.backend_store_uri:
        env_map[BACKEND_STORE_URI_ENV_VAR] = args.backend_store_uri
    if args.serve_artifacts:
        env_map[SERVE_ARTIFACTS_ENV_VAR] = "true"
    if args.artifacts_destination:
        env_map[ARTIFACTS_DESTINATION_ENV_VAR] = args.artifacts_destination
    if args.default_artifact_root:
        env_map[ARTIFACT_ROOT_ENV_VAR] = args.default_artifact_root

    print(f"Envmap: {env_map}")

    #opts = args.gunicorn_opts.split(" ") if args.gunicorn_opts else []
    opts = args.gunicorn_opts if args.gunicorn_opts else ""

    cmd = [
        "gunicorn", "-b", f"{args.host}:{args.port}", "-w", f"{args.n_workers}", "-k", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "server:app"
    ]
    run_command(cmd, env_map)

def main():
    args = parse_args()
    run_server(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Run like

```
python server.py --artifacts-destination s3://mlflow-mr --default-artifact-root s3://mlflow-mr --serve-artifacts
```

Then navigate to your browser and see the tracking server running! This allows you to insert custom FastAPI middleware in front of the tracking server